# Process.Start 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Tags: c#

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("../Shortcuts/slot1.lnk");
```

This line doesn't work.

I have checked that the file ending is correct and that the file is in the correct directory and yet it still doesn't work.

It should start the shortcut but it just says that it doesn't find the shortcut.

the folder structure is as follows **/folder1/Shortcuts/slot1.lnk** and the program is **/folder1/program/program.exe**

I would like to mention that I also load pictures the same way... They work this doesn't

```
pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("../Slots/slot2.jpg");
```

folder structure for this is the same so **/folder1/Slots/slot2.jpg**
and the program is **/folder1/program/program.exe**

I got it working by using double slashes

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("..\\Shortcuts\\slot1.lnk");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\maple\\Desktop\\slot1.lnk");
```

Note the absolute path, and the backslashes instead of forward slashes.

Once you get it working with absolute path, you can try the relative path, but be aware that generally you don't control what the current directory is when your user starts your application. If you really want to use relative paths, you should explicitly set current directory in your code.